# Convert LinkedHashMap to TreeMap

Tags: java

I have a map

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<...>>
```

of maps.

What is the best way to make deep conversion of my map to a tree map with respect to values (they should be converted from LinkedHashMap to TreeMap as well)? So I need to replace all `LinkedHashMap` to `TreeMap`.

I've tried to use constructor `new TreeMap<>(myLinkedHashMap)`. But it doesn't convert values (maps).

*UPD*

One more thing. Each value could have a map of maps.

```
Map <String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ...>>>>
```

And I need to change every LinkedHashMap in the structure.

Comment: At this point I'd definitely start to think about using a more appropriate data structure. The hideousness of having to do this conversion manually (as @sprinter correctly suggests) and recursively should ring alarm bells.

Comment: What do you mean by 'each value could have a map of maps'? Java is a typed language - if you want something that could be a string or could be a map then its type would need to be `Object`. I'm afraid your question isn't making a lot of sense.

Comment: @sprinter `Map <String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ...>>>>`. the nesting is unbound.

Comment: @Finkelson That's not legal Java - there's no such thing in the Java API as an infinitely nested map. You need to create your own class.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add each of the key value pairs manually to the new map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap();
map.forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k, new TreeMap(v));
```

Alternatively you could copy the original and then replace the values:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap(map);
result.replaceAll((k, v) -> new TreeMap(v));
```

This requires Java 8.

Comment: You'd also have to do it recursively though, because the values themselves will be maps too.

Comment: @biziclop I wrote this answer before OP's update. The update doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.8:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map1.put("3", "3");
    map1.put("2", "2");
    map1.put("1", "1");

    map.put("2",  map1);
    map.put("1", map1);

    System.out.println(map); // {2={3=3, 2=2, 1=1}, 1={3=3, 2=2, 1=1}}

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> resultMap = new TreeMap<>();

    map.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> resultMap.put(key, new TreeMap<>(map.get(key))));

    System.out.println(resultMap); // {1={1=1, 2=2, 3=3}, 2={1=1, 2=2, 3=3}}
```

Answer (score -1):

LinkedHashMap is a HashMap backed by a linked list
TreeMap is a B+ Tree
Since they are completely different data structures, there is no option but to do a manual copy.. no shortcuts. 
See a section of the source code of LinkedHashMap

```
/** The head of the doubly linked list. */
private transient Entry<K,V> header;
```

There isn't, and there is no need for this in TreeMap.. which is a BST.. see source code of TreeMap.put(K, V)

```
 if (cmp < 0) t = t.left;
else if (cmp > 0) t = t.right;
```

Comment: The argumentation isn't logical. `Array` and `Heap` are also 'completely different data structures'  and you can make a 'shortcut'.

Comment: In that case let me present to you a section of the source code of linkedHashMap>>     /**     * The head of the doubly linked list.     */    private transient Entry<K,V> header; << Did you get it? There isn't, and there is no need for this in TreeMap.. which is a BST.. see source code of put(K, V) >> if (cmp < 0)  t = t.left;else if (cmp > 0)  t = t.right;